# Динамический массив с возможностью обращения к элементу

Tags: java, динамические-массивы

У меня есть класс, и у него есть методы. Мне нужно создать массив объектов этого класса, чтобы я мог обращаться к методам этих элементов.
Когда я создал ArrayList, то я к ним могу обращаться только через get,  а через get я не могу использовать методы на них.
Программа крашит на этой строчке

```
Bullets.get(i).move();
```

Comment: Приведите сюда текст ошибки(исключения).

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю, что вы создали пустой динамический массив. То есть у вас что-то вроде

```
List<Bullet> Bullets = new ArrayList(123);
Bullets.get(2).move();
```

Так у вас ничего работать не будет, ибо сам список-то пустой, просто ёмкость у него будет та, которую вы указали в конструкторе.

Необходимо добавить все элементы, с которыми вы хотите работать, в этот список, и только после этого обращаться к его элементам:

```
List<Bullet> Bullets = new ArrayList(123);
Bullets.add(new Bullet("bullet 1"));        // Индекс = 0
Bullets.add(new Bullet("bullet 2"));        // Индекс = 1
Bullets.add(new Bullet("The best bullet")); // Индекс = 2
Bullets.get(2).move();
```

P.S. Старайтесь придерживаться конвенции именования Java. Называйте переменные с маленькой буквы, e.g. `List<Bullet> bullets`

Answer (score 0):

И еще проверьте доступ для методов. Если они private или без спецификатора доступа, то в другом пакете вызвать их будет нельзя. А вообще stackTrace ошибки в студию, так сразу всё станет ясно)